# Resolve not called for child routes in angular 2

Tags: angular, router, resolve

router details:

this is the route details of a feature module, being lazy loaded.
the route is /customers

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '',
component: CustomersComponent,
children: [
  { path: '',    component: CustomersListComponent },
   { path: ':id',    component: CustomersDetailsComponent,
   resolve: {
      xxx: CustomerResolve1
    }
    ,children: [
     { path: ':module',    component: CustomersModuleDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      xxx: CustomerResolve2
    }
   }
   ] }
 ]
}
```

];

in the 2 resolvers, i just write to the console that i've reached the resolver.

if i enter the following url:

```
http://localhost:4200/customers/45/invoices
```

the 2 resolvers are executed.

if i press a button that executes the following in my ts:

```
this.router.navigate(['customers','100','invoices']);
```

only the first resolver is executed !

as my inner most component "CustomersModuleDetailsComponent" shows information
based on the url, it's not being refreshed as the resolver for that component isn't being executed.

any suggestions ? 
(beside changing the resolver to a guard)
(and besides transferring the id from the father component to the son component via @input, or eventEmitter)

Thanks

Comment: your should use absolute path names

Comment: @RomanC can you explain please ?

Comment: Dude, you should add this to your router config :)

Comment: @RomanC
how can that be done with the use of lazy loading modules ?
the route described above, is of a feature module. the "/customers" path is defined in the app.module.routing.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It seems there is a bug in Angular Router.

The children's resolvers are not triggered in this case when parent route param is modified.

Comment: this is indeed a problem with the router, and was fixed in the 4.0 beta 3 release.

Comment: effectively:
router: call resolver when upstream params change ([#12942](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12942)) ([d4d3782](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d4d3782))