# Parent resolver is not called on child lazy loaded routes

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-resolver

I am trying to set side bar routes based on different user role privileges. The code for setting side bar routes is in site-resolver service. Which I have called in parent path which I think should be also called for its child routes. But instead, this resolver is getting called only when I refresh the particular child route.

Here's the example of my site-routing service:

```
{
path: ':siteId',
resolve: { site: SiteResolverService },
children: [
  // ... other child routes
  {
    path: 'jsa-training-user-assigned-jsa',
    loadChildren: () => import('../jsa-quiz/jsa-quiz.module').then(m => m.JsaQuizModule),
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    data: { expectedRole: [UserRole.SystemAdmin, UserRole.JsaCreator, UserRole.SiteAdmin, UserRole.PasscodeUser] },
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  // ... other child routes
]
```

here in this route i want the resolver to get called without refreshing, so i have tried below, but not working.

> runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496499/resolve-not-called-for-child-routes-in-angular-2

Comment: @hrdkisback yeah I checked that question before posting this one but that question didn't have any specific solution apparently..

Comment: Please post `SiteResolverService` code.

Comment: @hrdkisback but that isn't necessary until that resolver gets called. I put alert in that resolver's constructor and main thing is it isn't getting called.

Comment: what if you remove `resolve: { site: SiteResolverService }` from parent route and provide on each child routes. Refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-resolve-demo

Comment: @hrdkisback yes as a last option I then used that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The resolver is called when you refresh a child route because the whole route tree is triggered, while accessing a child route from a parent will only trigger the child route.

You can still get the result of the parent resolver in the child component by accessing the `route.parent` :

Child component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.route.parent.snapshot.data);
}
```

Comment: That clears the doubt yeah! but I have set the routes in the resolver so I don't want any data from the resolver, I just want it to get triggered for the lazy loaded module given in my code. And that is module and not component.